# Unexpected behavior with StartsWith and unicode

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

While working on an issue, I encountered an interesting use case. The `StartsWith` method (and maybe some others) returns true for the following 2 cases:

```
"\u0000Example".StartsWith("Example");          // returns true
"\u0000Example".StartsWith("\u0000Example");    // returns true
```

Repository with this example and unit tests: https://github.com/DeanMilojevic/UnicodeInvestigation

As I didn't have time to dive deeper into the implementation of the method, I was wondering if this is a "bug" or expected behavior?

Otherwise when I find out more in my free time, will update the question with additional information.

Comment: Here's another data point: `"\u0000Example".StartsWith("Example", StringComparison.Ordinal)`

Comment: Also, note that this changed in .NET 5, which strongly suggests it's related to the move from NLS to ICU

Comment: @canton7 I had the same feeling about this as well. Was planning to debug and see what is happening at one point, when I find some time. I am considering maybe submitting a ticket on GitHub as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the breaking changes introduced in .NET 5 is the transition from [NLS to ICU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/globalization/5.0/icu-globalization-api) globalization libraries on Windows. I don't see any mention of it in your post but assuming you are using .NET 5 then this behaviour does not appear to be a bug.

To quote the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/string-comparison-net-5-plus#behavioral-differences):

> If you use functions like string.IndexOf(string) without calling the overload that takes a StringComparison argument, you might intend to perform an ordinal search, but instead you inadvertently take a dependency on culture-specific behavior. **Since NLS and ICU implement different logic in their linguistic comparers, the results of methods like string.IndexOf(string) can return unexpected values.**

If you take a look at [this table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/string-comparison-net-5-plus#default-search-and-comparison-types), you'll see that the `string.StartsWith` method uses `CurrentCulture` comparison by default when passing a string parameter. Since you're doing a *culture-specific* comparison (by not specifying the `StringComparison` parameter) then it seems that the ICU library, however it goes about its implementation, ignores the null unicode character `\u0000` whereas the NLS library seemingly doesn't.

Judging by your code, it looks like what you wanted to do was perform an ordinal search which can be done using: `"\u0000Example".StartsWith("Example", StringComparison.Ordinal)` which will correctly return `false`.

It is recommended to enable [code analyzers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/string-comparison-net-5-plus#enable-code-analyzers) in your project to help you identify code that is unexpectedly using a linguistic comparer when an ordinal one was likely intended.

The recommended rules to enable are:

[CA1307: Specify StringComparison for clarity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1307)

[CA1309: Use ordinal StringComparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1309)

[CA1310: Specify StringComparison for correctness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1310)

To enable these code analysis rules and have them cause build errors, simply add the following to your project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AnalysisMode>AllEnabledByDefault</AnalysisMode>
  <WarningsAsErrors>$(WarningsAsErrors);CA1307;CA1309;CA1310</WarningsAsErrors>
</PropertyGroup>
```